# На Windows-10 файловая система на внешнем HDD становится RAW

Tags: windows-10, файловая-система, hdd, внешние-устройства

Факты.

1. Количество подключенных HDD у меня более 10. Док-станции Agestar, USB3, некоторые рассчитаны на 1 диск, некоторые - на 2.
2. На Win-7 за годы работы ни разу не было каких-либо проблем.
3. На Win-10 за 7 месяцев потерял 10 дисков по 3 Тб каждый. Порча файловой системы происходит неожиданно, иногда после недель или месяцев работы, иногда - через несколько часов после установки диска. При обращении к испорченному диску появляется сообщение: "Не удается опознать присутствующую на томе файловую систему..."
4. Некоторые док-станции подключены прямо к компьютеру, некоторые - через USB-хаб. Порча происходит в обоих случаях.
5. Во время порчи напряжение питания стабильно. Порча происходит, когда компьютер запущен и работает, а не во время включения/выключения.
6. Порча произошла несколько раз на новом мощном моноблоке DELL и на стареньком ноутбуке Acer. И там, и там Win-10 версии 2004. То есть тип компьютера не важен, важна установленная ОС. Есть указания на то, что на версии Win-10 младше 2004 HDD не портятся.
7. Антивирус Avast установлен только на одной машине, на другом компе используется MS Defender, стороннего антивируса там нет. Но ФС слетает в обоих случаях. Следовательно, антивирус вне подозрений. Излишне говорить, что за все время работы машин вирусы на них не обнаруживались.
8. Если док-станция на 2 диска, то всегда портятся *одновременно* оба HDD (!).
9. Портятся как старые диски, так и новые из коробки. Портятся диски брендов Seagate и Toshiba (другие не использовал).
10. Показательный случай: диск наполовину был записан на компьютере с Win-7, потом HDD подключил к компу с Win-10 и там были записаны еще файлы. Я работал с новыми файлами, и вдруг в какой-то момент эти новые файлы стали недоступны, при этом папки и файлы, записанные на Win-7 читались. После перезагрузки компьютера весь диск стал недоступен.
11. А вот последний случай. После копирования диска Seagate с некоторым количеством плохих секторов на новый диск Toshiba (в спаренной док-станции) я решил зайти в папку с нечитаемыми файлами на старом диске Seagate. И в этот момент появилось сообщение, что чтение невозможно. После этого оба диска оказались недоступными (хотя в этот момент я работал с одним, первым, диском).
12. Если диск испортился (на Win-10), то он становится недоступен и на Win-7.
13. На компьютере Dell штатная утилита обслуживания рапортует, что все драйверы свежие и их обновление не требуется. Но на присоединенных дисках файловая система массово превращается в RAW.
14. Во всех случаях оснастка "Управление дисками" поврежденные HDD видит и может присваивать им буквы. Диск показывается как исправный, дается его объем, но на месте ожидаемого типа ФС стоит RAW.
15. chkdsk пишет: Тип файловой системы NTFS. Не удается прочитать первый загрузочный сектор NTFS. Попытка чтения второго загрузочного сектора NTFS. Невозможно определить версию тома и его состояние. Работа chkdsk прервана
16. Если провести быстрое форматирование, то все файлы можно спасти программой Recuva, но структура папок теряется. Сохранение требует нескольких суток непрерывной работы компьютера.
17. Программа Diskintrnals Uneraser также спасает файлы, при этом предварительно диск форматировать не нужно.
18. Консольная утилита Windows File Rescue поврежденные диски "не берет", но после быстрого форматирования, наверное, сможет восстановить файлы (не пробовал, но собираюсь).
19. Внутренние диски, как механические HDD, так и SSD, не портятся.
20. В Интернете толкового разбора аналогичных случаев не нашел. Есть короткие обрывочные сведения без решения.

ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?

Comment: Всё указывает на проблемы в таблице разделов. Которую можно восстановиться не прибегая к форматированию. На самом деле нужно ещё больше инфы. Проводились ли тесты самих HDD (если нет, нужно провести той же Викторией, желательно одновременно для 10 дисков) ? Питание док станций от сети или USB ?  Сколько дисков на одной шине USB ? Как насчёт других файловых систем, воспроизводится ли на них та же проблема? Используются ли сторонние утилиты для работы с дисками?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не там ищете. У меня через несколько лет успешной работы именно на Win7 контейнер на 2 диска Agestar убил так основную таблицу на одном из дисков, после чего я всё понял и перестал эти контейнеры вообще использовать. То ли у них софт глючный, то ли БП со временем начинает чудить, но проблема, мне кажется, не в системе, а именно в сердитых и дешёвых Agestar. Они и до того странновато себя вели, но диски не портили. А потом внезапно бац - и RAW. Утилитой какой-то все файлы можно вытащить, но, блин, очень это всё неприятно.

Comment: MilkyWay, тесты HDD до порчи не проводились, после порчи - только chkdsk. Питание док-станций строго от сети. На одной шине USB от 1-2 дисков (это без USB-хаба) до где-то 6 шт через хаб. Использовал только NTFS, про другие ФС информации нет. До порчи никакие сторонние утилиты не использовались, после порчи - утилиты типа unerase. Спасибо за наводку на Викторию.